# How to find layer names within vector tiles, without TileJSON or the .mbtiles file?

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, wmts, vector-tiles

I'm trying to use an endpoint in Mapbox vector tile format. I can access the .pbf's ok, but there's no documentation or TileJSON endpoint.

**How can I find the names of layers that exist within the tiles?** That is, the value that I would set to `source-layer` in a `vector` source in Mapbox-GL-JS.

Theoretically this must be doable, but I don't know any tool that lets me achieve this.

(In this particular case, it's a WMTS endpoint on GeoServer, but I'd be more interested in solutions that work generally.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're okay to write a NodeJS script you can use

```
const request = require('request');
const VectorTile = require('@mapbox/vector-tile').VectorTile;
const Pbf = require('pbf');
const zlib = require('zlib');

request({
    url: 'https://example.com/1/2/3.pbf',
    encoding: null

}, (err, response, body) => {
    try {
         body = zlib.gunzipSync(body);
    } catch (e) {

    }
    const tile = new VectorTile(new Pbf(body));
    console.log('Vector source layers found: ', Object.keys(tile.layers).join(', '))
})
```

https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js#api-reference

Try this on Runkit: https://runkit.com/stevebennett/get-layer-names-and-keys-from-vector-tile

Comment: Awesome, that worked with a couple of tweaks. It seems unzipping of the body is supported automatically by Request, so removed that.

Comment: Ok, too hasty. Updated version works with both gzipped and non-gzipped sources. Maybe the gzip is at lower level. Who knows.

Comment: Maybe it depends if the HTTP response includes the right headers or not.

Comment: I've made a runkit version of this here: https://runkit.com/stevebennett/get-layer-names-and-keys-from-vector-tile

Answer (score 4):

Using Andrew's code above, I've now made a website to solve this problem:

```
http://stevage.github.io/vector-inspector
```

Just paste the URL of any tile, and it lists the names of the layers and their attributes.

Or, as an API:

```
https://vector-inspector.glitch.me/tile/https:/tiles.planninglabs.nyc/data/v3/14/4826/6157.pbf
```

Comment: Perfect, only thing is if you can wrote something, easy reusable.  input parameter is http://.....pbf, output is json as { layer1:xxx, layer2:yyy etc.....}

Comment: can you make a rest service?  http://stevage.github.io/vector-inspector?pbf=http://xxx....pbf,   then response as {[layer1, layer2, layer3...etc.]}

Comment: Done: https://vector-inspector.glitch.me/tile/https:/tiles.planninglabs.nyc/data/v3/14/4826/6157.pbf